# external usb harddrive prevents startup of Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, boot

An external usb harddrive attached to a Windows Server 2003 (yes, we know it is old) seems to prevent the server from starting up (after a reboot or power recycle).

I get the message: **"Bootmgr is missing. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart".**
If I unplug the drive at startup and press CTRL+ALT+DEL it is fine. After startup I plug the drive back in and all is fine.

Is there a way to make the "bootmgr is missing" go away when the external usb drive is attached at startup?
I can't find anything in the (old) bios to skip this step.

Comment: The BIOS boot order/precedence would indeed be the obvious place to configure that the server won't boot from anything but it's own harddrive.

Comment: It is set to own HDD first, but still it seems to take the external drive. Any other suggestions? Is there something on the drive itself that can be done?
I don't see any other options in BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the boot order in the BIOS. Depending on your BIOS, this could be in 1 of 2 places.

1. Some will list all drives together, in this case simply move your internal HDD to the top of the list (or at least above the external drive).
2. A different style of BIOS may have one list for internal drives and a separate list for ordering different types of bootable locations, such as internal drives, USB devices, the DVD tray, and the network. Make sure that the internal drives are listed above USB/external bootable devices in this case.

It may also be possible in your BIOS to simply disable USB boot altogether.